# How to reinstall Windows Movie Maker (XP)

Tags: windows-xp

Windows Movie Maker has this 'feature' of forgetting its transitions.

The obvious fix is to re-install it - but since it comes with Windows via a service patch, its not a standalone thing to re-install.

Anyone come up with a trick to address this?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to upgrading the video cameras to HD ones we have gone for a new HD compatible movie maker package - Cyberlink's [PowerDirector](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdirector/overview_en_US.html).

It seems to be more flexible/powerful (it does cost), although more flaky too... but at least you uninstall/re-install it without reinstalling the whole OS...

Answer (score 2):

You can download the installer from CNET [here](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-Movie-Maker-Windows-XP/3000-13631_4-10165075.html?tag=mncol;pop).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows XP machine by hand but I'd figure it's in:

```
Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> Add/Remove Windows Components
```

If that doesn't work try the following:
Use Windows Explorer to go to:

```
%systemroot%\inf
```

Find a file named **moviemk.inf** and use the right-mouse button on it. In the context menu choose: **Install**

Comment: Thanks, but it does not show up there :(

Comment: Looks like the .inf is available for download in a few places. Here's one: http://www.dllempire.com/moviemk.inf/36e6/download/

Comment: I think we tried the moviemk.inf option without success - but will check again and revert back...